# PowerPoint VBA lock all shapes

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Does anyone know how to lock all shapes from all slides in vba and also unlock in another macro?

I've the beggining but I can't find how to apply the lock function.

```
Sub test()
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each oSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
        oSlide.Shapes.SelectAll
        xxx.locked
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we go

```
Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
Sub Lock()
Dim oSlide As Slide
Dim oShape As Shape
Dim slideIndex As Long
Set oSlide = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide
oSlideIndex = oSlide.slideIndex

On Error Resume Next
For Each oSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
ActivePresentation.Slides(oSlide.slideIndex).Select
Sleep (100)
ActivePresentation.Slides(oSlide.slideIndex).Shapes.Range.Locked = msoTrue
Next
ActivePresentation.Slides(oSlideIndex).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Leave out the .Select statements. They're not necessary, they slow down your code and can, in some situations, cause your code not to work at all.  As a general rule NEVER select anything unless you absolutely need to.

Comment: in fact in my case, if a don't select the slide before lock or unlock, the code as no effect, unlike other operations like inserting text     

(I've Microsoft 365 for enterprise)

Comment: I've put a timer because there's a random problem, the lock or unlock does not work without timer

Comment: >> "in fact in my case, if a don't select the slide before lock or unlock, the code as no effect"  You might want to try repairing your Office installation; it shouldn't matter.  Selecting slides may take enough time that you need to toss in the timer function; one problem compounding another, so to speak.

Answer (score 2):

Air code, but it should work, assuming you have a version of PPT that supports .Locked:

```
sub test
Dim oSlide As Slide
Dim oShape as Shape
On Error Resume Next
For Each oSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
For Each oShape in oSlide.Shapes
   oShape.Locked = True
Next
Next
end sub
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but it does not work perfecly, itt unlock only the current page, that's strange

Comment: Are you using the code exactly as posted above, or have you modified it to suit your specific needs? If the latter, please post the code you're using.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

the correct macro need to activate the slide before processing
I'm looking for the next step "oSlide.Shapes.SelectAll" with lock to accelerate, if anyone...

```
 Sub Lock()  
    Dim oSlide As Slide  
    dim oShape As Shape  
    Dim slideIndex As Long
    
Set oSlide = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide 
oslideIndex = oSlide.slideIndex
    
On Error Resume Next 
For Each oSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides 

ActivePresentation.Slides(oSlide.slideIndex).Select
            For Each oShape In oSlide.Shapes
            oShape.Locked = True
            Next  
    Next  
    ActivePresentation.Slides(oslideIndex).Select  
    End Sub
```