# PowerPoint VSTO - how to lock Shapes (manually you would do this in the Selection Pane)?

Tags: c#, powerpoint, vsto, office-addins, comaddin

The following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72574565/powerpoint-vba-lock-all-shapes) explains how to do this in VBA by setting the Locked property on the PowerPoint Shape. However, when trying to do this in C# as a VSTO Addon the Locked property is not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ShapeRange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.shaperange) class doesn't expose the `Locked` property. If that works in VBA then you may try using the late-binding technology to call hidden or private members. Use the [Type.InvokeMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.invokemember?view=net-6.0) method to make such calls in .net applications.

Comment: This appears to have worked! Many thanks, I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@Eugene Astafieve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1603351/eugene-astafiev).
The following line achieves what I wanted to do:

```
var LockedVar = myGroup.GetType().InvokeMember("Locked", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, myGroup, new object[] { OfficeCore.MsoTriState.msoTrue });
```

Where: myGroup is a PPT Shape (in my case a Grouped Shape)

Comment: There's no need to Share your own Answer and thank the other Answerer
Just mark his Answer as the Accepted Answer
if you really wanna be nice, write Thanks as a comment :)